# Software to re-center a fisheye image

Tags: distortion, perspective, fisheye

I am looking for easy to use software that works on OS X and can "re-center" an equal-area projection fisheye image.

What do I mean by "re-center"?  The perspective correction tools built into many software essentially compute what the image would have looked like if the camera had pointed in a different direction.  I am looking for the equivalent operation for fisheye images.  I want to do this without changing the projection.

I know that Hugin can do this, but there are no binaries for the last two versions and the version before that is awfully crashy.

Comment: You can only "re-center" with a full spherical equirectangular, _not_ with a single fisheye image.

Comment: @inkista You can re-center an image of any projection.  The boundaries of the re-centered image won't be a rectangle of course.  But that doesn't matter.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this question? You want to flatten (defisheye) an existing image shot with a fisheye lens and then recreate the fisheye effect centered in a different portion of the flattened image; is that correct?

Comment: @travelgasm Other than Hugin, no. It might be easiest to try to find a usable binary of Hugin. Yes, your description is correct, although _actually_ flattening (rather than doing a direct transform to the target mapping) would degrade quality.